# Android In-App billing VS a payed app?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm a developer and I own some application and want to protect my applications. 
I implemented the In-App billing but I find that it's not stable since we have two api's for that API3 and API2 and my application will not officially be available for all devices.

My questions is what is the best to be done? payed apps or in-app billing!

P.S: if you have any idea about which is the best to use API3 or API2 would be great!
Also if you have any tutorial could be fine.

Comment: Support API2 and API3.  At runtime, determine the Android version and use the correct API

Comment: did you have any tutorial for API2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My flurry stats results shows domination of Android 2.3+
API3 works even on 2.2

The rest is 1-3%. You should multiply these percent on factor that the users with old phones unlikely to spent much money on paid apps.

Someone with `Galaxy S III` is more likely to pay $1 then someone with `Galaxy ACE` these both phones support API3

Comment: I don't know if this is the new Play issue ! but after some tests not all device supports API3 even if they have the new google play apk ! I test this on 30 devices ! and I'm shocked that there are 13 device does not support the API !!!!! they give result 3 on all transaction which means that the play does not support this API !

Comment: It is not device. May be it is users Google account that does not allow payment. No credit card in file or something like that.